# Publish Maven "Vendor Branches"

Tags: java, git, maven, jenkins

#### Basic Question

I want to be able to locally build with maven a patched fork of some Java github code using Jenkins and then publish it to Artifactory (or some equivalent repository manager). Is there a pattern for doing this? Is there a way for me to build a project and publish it using someone else's POM but patching the version number and SCM details?

#### Background

My company has a Java project which depends on an external Java module. We use Artifactory to manage our dependencies to do this. No problem here.

However, occasionally we want to make code changes (bug fixes or enhancements) to the external Java module (let's call it "CoolFramework 1.0" and say that it's source is freely available on GitHub). So I fork the repository, make the code change and issue a pull request. Sometime later, the owner of the CoolFramework project decides to release version 1.1 of the project with my bug fix or shiny new feature.

The question I have relates to the time in between. Clearly, I want to be able to have the bug fixes or enhancements in my project as soon as I've developed them. I'd like to push them into Artifactory as a kind of snapshot release (perhaps versioned as cool-framework-1.0-MYCOMPANY-1 where the "-1" at the end represents the Jenkins build number or some other unique reference). However, all of the release management stuff that maven does seems to relate to either publishing a SNAPSHOT or pushing the final release and doesn't deal with this intermediate process (understandably).

Is there a common process for doing this? Mr Google didn't find one for me but then I may not be asking him the right questions.

Comment: Why do you need the Jenkins build number in the version?

Comment: I need to be able to refer to a specific version so that I get rebuild reliability. For instance, my main project depends on CoolFramework 1.0. I make a change to CoolFramework and call that CoolFramework 1.0-1. This is published to my local artifact repo. Then I make a further change, that gets version 1.0-2. Build number seems to be the logical way of getting a sequence of numbers. I want to be able to refer to each individual version from my main project directly, rather than being forced to always take the "snapshot" version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what exact problem you have. If you are talking about versioning I think this is usual approach.  You just increment version and add a modifier, maven will select it until vendor version released. So, you branch vendor's code 1.0, you modify it's version to 1.1-MYCOMPANY.1 and develop it incrementing the last number. Also you publish merge requests to the vendor. Then vendor is ready, he releases 1.1 and it supersedes your qualifier. If you discover that something still is missing by vendor, you ship the next version 1.2-MYCOMPANY.1

Comment: I am not sure how the official 1.1 from the vendor will supersede 1.1-MYCOMPANY automatically? @steve-n will still have to remove the qualifier from dependency declaration.

Comment: @JBaruch It doesn't happen magically, but there are tools which allow to display and update versions, e.g. http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/examples/display-dependency-updates.html

Comment: It seems like I'm going the right way with this then. I think the only other thing I need to address is how to manipulate the contents of the original POM (i.e. override its version and change the SCM location). I think I can use the versions:set plugin to update version numbers. I think my best approach for the rest of the POM management is to change it in my forked repo. Fork the repo -> make a branch to track my changes in (master tracks the original repo) -> edit POM in branch -> build from branch -> merge changes from master when necessary.

Comment: @SteveN I think changing pom is correct approach, as it describes your project dependencies and properties. If the vendor would change it too, you should rely on merging facilities and merge your changes with changes coming from the vendor.